# Firebase phone auth replaces userimage and Displayname

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase to create user account with email and password first and later I update a profile image which  I can acess with 
currentuser.getphotourl(). by following code

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                // user account created successfully
                showMessage("Account created");
                // after we created user account we need to update his profile picture and name
                updateUserInfo(name, pickedImgUri, mAuth.getCurrentUser());

            } else {

                // account creation failed
                showMessage("account creation failed" + task.getException().getMessage());
                regBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loadingProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        }
    });
```

In Home, Now the user image and email is diplayed. But In next activity when I user phone auth and enter the code and then in homeactivity user image and email both are blank..

I want to use the user phone number for later acesss not to signin. But I thought it is better to create database only for phone, use phone  auth instead and retrive phone number whenever necessary. But Using phone auth, old email, profile url is replaced or similar error occurs.

How can I resolve it? Is it expected behaviour?

Comment: What is the code inside this method `updateUserInfo`?

Answer (score 0):

So what I can understand from your question is that:

- Login Successful
- HomeActivity `email` and `profilePic` displays correctly
- Goto next activity and user enters phone number
- Come back to HomeActivity and `email` and `profilePic` are now empty.

If this is the case you can store the user `email` and `profileUrl` in savedInstanceState:

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("message", "This is a saved message");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRestoreInstanceState", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

And in onCreate, you can check every time if savedInstance state is not null, then get and set data:

```
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        String message = savedInstanceState.getString("key");
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Or you can just simply set the email and profilePic in the `onResume` itself.
This will set email and profilePic everytime OnResume is called and might fix the problem.

Comment: But that is saved locally, when user login from another device and still the profile image and display name are empty now which is the main problem I'm getting.

Comment: So you can store them in Shared preferences. Buy don't forget to clear those when user logs out.